# Net SMPT smtp.data usage in Ruby

Tags: ruby, smtp

I have a question about Ruby Net SMTP

I have this code which is working perfectly fine:

```
to = 'aaa@bbb.com'
from = 'ccc@bbb.com'
message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: #{from}
To: #{to}
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('111.111.111.111') do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message message, from, to
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
to = 'aaa@bbb.com'
from = 'ccc@bbb.com'
smtp = Net::SMTP.start('111.111.111.111')
   smtp.data {|f|
      f.puts "From: #{from}"
      f.puts "To: #{to}"
      f.puts "Subject: Email test"
      f.puts ""
      f.puts "Testing"
   }
smtp.finish
```

I am getting the following error:

> /usr/share/ruby/net/smtp.rb:956:in `check_continue': could not get 3xx
>   (503: 503 5.5.1 Error: need RCPT command (Net::SMTPUnknownError) )
>     from /usr/share/ruby/net/smtp.rb:896:in`block in data'     from
>   /usr/share/ruby/net/smtp.rb:941:in `critical'     from
>   /usr/share/ruby/net/smtp.rb:895:in`data'     from test.rb:84:in `'

Thank you.

-Andrey

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Of course forgot to post error message.

Comment: Still cannot find the problem.